# How do I block all BlazingFast.io IP ranges?

Tags: iptables, spam

In my logs I've been noticing several cases where frequent requests from an IP spam POST requests to a specific Wordpress script. What all of these spam source IPs have in common, is that they originate from BlazingFast.io's servers. I've been adding DROP rules to `iptables` for each IP separately. Is there a way I could add just one rule that would DROP all requests from any BlazingFast IPs?

IP ranges: https://ipinfo.io/AS60033

Comment: There's less than 17 blocks there (some of them are listed 3 times, once as a /23 and then twice as two /24s). What's stopping you from adding one rule per netblock?

Comment: Like this, for example: `-s 185.62.0.0/16`?

Comment: I added them now by the `/24`.

Comment: I once wrote a [script to generate iptables rules given an AS number](http://www.ringingliberty.com/2014/07/12/matching-autonomous-system-numbers-in-iptables/). You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If BlazingFast are not using anycast you can drop there packet like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s BlazingFast.io -j DROP
```

but if they are using using it, you can do it by adding setting this rule to some file and restore it every 15 min for example.
you can use crontab for that

It is not the perfect solution but its work most of times

Comment: I thought `-s` could only take an IP [block] as the argument?